# Generating Thermal Printer (Zebra Printer) Sized PDFs for FedEx Labels

Tags: pdf, printer, print-to-pdf

## Background

I own a company which does a lot of FedEx Ground shipping. We have a 3rd party fulfillment center, which stores some of our inventory and at our request ships it. Zebra/Thermal printers are the most cost effective shipping label printers available and our 3rd party fulfillment center has one. I want to generate the labels locally then e-mail the 3rd party fulfillment center a PDF of the labels which they can then print out on their printer.

## Problem

The trouble is, I can't seem to figure out how to print these 4" x 6" labels to a PDF, as FedEx (both ship manager and fedex.com) uses javascript to detect what printer I have.

## Question

What's a clever way to send my 3rd party fulfillment center a PDF (or equivalent) of our 4" x 6" zebra thermal printer labels so they can print them out without re-entering the data?

Answer (score 1):

I solve a similar (but not identical - this may not work for you) issue (CR80 cards, primary generation system does not talk to printer, device that talks to printer doesn't have the ability to run the database, so I hand it a PDF) by defining a custom paper size for printers I do have on the generation system, which matches the card-printer card-size on the other system. So long as I first do a page setup with the custom paper size, then generate the PDF, the PDF generated on that system prints fine on the other system.

Answer (score 0):

Get [BullZip](http://www.bullzip.com/),  Its free and it is a print driver that prints to pdf files.  I use it all the time and have never had a print job not accepted by it.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of the desktop software can save labels as image files which you could send over to your warehouse.

I'd also check with your salesman as I know FedEx has technology consultants who might be able to help.